# How to get all childs of a node using php xpath?

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, descendant

In the code below:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class='even'>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='even'>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I run, `$xpath->query("//tr[@class='even']")`

It only shows me the contents of the `<th>` tags. Shouldn't I be getting the contents of the `<td>` as well i.e. everything inside the `<tr>` tags?

If not how can I get the td without having to write separate ones like this:

```
$xpath->query("//tr[@class='even']/th")
$xpath->query("//tr[@class='even']/td")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` selector that select any tag.

```
$xpath->query("//tr[@class='even']/*")
```

The above code select every child of `tr.even`. Also you can use `|` (OR) operator like bottom code.

```
$xpath->query("//tr[@class='even']/td | //tr[@class='even']/th");
```